# Is it possible to detect cellphone IDs in an enclosed area

Tags: rf, cellphone

I'm working on a project where I need to be able to identify different cellphones in an area.
Ideally I need a way to identify when specific cellphones enter and exit a range - this could be IMEI or Mac addresses (or any other unique ID).
I know that this is possible with wifi to get the MAC but it depends on the phone being set to autodiscover open networks - is it possible by using some RF device/scanner?

Comment: Obviously, it's *possible*, because that's how cell towers work in the first place. Maybe you could just get a commercial "nano cell"? But to get a meaningful answer to your question, you'll have to be more specific about what "an area" is, and any other implementation constraints you might have.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Basically I need a way to understand and identify the people in a building via their cellphones

Answer (score 2):

See "IMSI catcher": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMSI-catcher

The legality of this varies, and I believe there are more passive versions available. Certainly there are companies offering this as a service (for use in shopping centres to get customer information, for example).

Building your own *may* be possible with software-defined-radio and "OpenBTS".

Answer (score 0):

It is theoretically possible to passively monitor all the cellular uplink channels and notice devices active in your area but in reality it would be highly impractical for the following reasons:

The first obstacle is that in any region with multiple cellular carriers operating multiple technologies (2G/3G/4G), there is a *lot* of spectrum in use. In the US, for example, there is something on the order of [400Mhz of uplink spectrum in use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_frequencies#United_States). That's a lot to monitor. You may be able to pare it down somewhat by monitoring more intelligently (i.e. monitoring only [RACH for GSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Um_interface#Random_Access_Channel_.28RACH.29) but that requires ongoing maintenance (active cells can change at any time) and still requires a bunch of receivers and antennas on different bands.

If you're only concerned with omnidirectional proximity, one (large, expensive) set of equipment is all you need. If you need to do any sort of triangulation, multiply by at least three.

The second obstacle is that you are not likely to see meaningful identifiers (IMEI, IMSI, ESN, MEID, etc.) in the clear very often (if ever). GSM, for example, uses short-term, arbitrarily-assigned [TMSIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporary_Mobile_Subscriber_Identity#TMSI) specifically to protect subscribers' true unique identities from eavesdropping.